# last-child css not working correctly in chrome?

Tags: css, css-selectors

This issue only exists in Chrome, works fine in IE/FF...

Example: http://www.8wayrun.com/media/algol-killer-combos.621/

On the right side, you will see a list for "Characters", and below it: algol nightmare siegfried. This is actually an inline unordered list, with the following parameters:

```
.mediaDetails li::after {
    content: ',';
}
.mediaDetails li:last-child::after {
    content: '';
}
```

In IE/FF this works great, you end up with a list that looks like "algol, nightmare, siegfried". However, in Chrome it looks like "algol, nightmare, siegfried,"; there is a comma after the last-child when there shouldn't be. The weird thing, is if I highlight siegfried, the comma will disappear; if I open up the Chrome Inspector, the comma will disappear.

Is there an error in my code that is causing this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uhm, it looks good to me:

[image]

I'm using Google Chrome 10.0.648.119 BETA (I expect the same will happen in the stable version).

Comment: I'm using 10.0.648.119 stable.

Comment: 10.0.648.114 beta mac here and it does happen. This is really hacky though, you really ought to handle it from the html.